# Excel VBA pivot table filtering by barcode

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to create sub, that helps filter list of goods by selecting few barcodes. I know I can do it manually, but it's very long and frustrating, since there are about ~2000 unique barcodes. I've recorded a Macro and found a few similar answers here, but i get an error "Run-time error '1004': Application defined or object-defined error' it stucks when PI.value gets assigned true or false: "PI.Visible = True; Pi.Visible = False".

Code:

> Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
>
> ```
> Dim MyNames() As Variant
> Dim objPivotField As PivotField
> Dim i As Long
> Dim PI As PivotItem
> Set objPivotField = _
> ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(Index:="[Prekė].[Barkodas].[Barkodas]")
> MyNames = Array("4770349225872", "4770033220077", "7622400004773")
> With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(Index:="[Prekė].[Barkodas].[Barkodas]")
>
>     For i = LBound(MyNames) To UBound(MyNames)
>
>     For Each PI In .PivotItems
>         If PI.Name = MyNames(i) Then
>         PI.Visible = True
>     Else
>         PI.Visible = False
>     End If
>     Next PI
>     Next i
> End With End Sub
> ```

And here's Macro that I recorded for filtering:

> ```
> ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
>     "[Prekė].[Barkodas].[Barkodas]").VisibleItemsList = Array("", _
>     "[Prekė].[Barkodas].&[4750398000132]", "", "[Prekė].[Barkodas].&[4046234141238]", _
>     "[Prekė].[Barkodas].&[4770248342625]")
> ```

Comment: Could you post more about the setup of the pivot table? I tried a small example with logic similar to yours and it worked, but I used With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Barkodas")

Comment: Also, looping through the barcodes once and checking each PivotItem against MyNames would go faster than looping through the barcodes three times, each time checking for a single barcode

Answer (score 0):

As written above in the comments, here is the method I used to filter a pivot table with VBA:

[image: pivot table setup]

```
Option Explicit
Sub FilterPivotTable()

Dim PT1 As PivotTable
Dim PT1Barkodas As PivotField
Dim MyNames() As Variant
Dim PivotIdx As Long

'assign table, field and array values for easy reference
Set PT1 = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")
Set PT1Barkodas = PT1.PivotFields("Barkodas")
MyNames = Array("4770349225872", "4770033220077", "7622400004773")

With PT1Barkodas

    'loop through all the barcodes
    For PivotIdx = 1 To PT1Barkodas.PivotItems.Count

        'logic to check if the current barcode is in the MyNames array
        If UBound(Filter(MyNames, .PivotItems(PivotIdx))) > -1 Then
            IsInArray = True
        Else
            IsInArray = False
        End If

        'if the barcode was not in the MyNames array, hide it
        If IsInArray = False Then
            .PivotItems(PivotIdx).Visible = False
        End If

    Next PivotIdx

End With

End Sub
```

Running this script filtered PivotTable1 according to MyNames:

[image: result]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. This seems to be a good way to do this, but when assigning visible value, I get an error on this line:
`code       If IsInArray = False Then
            .PivotItems(PivotIdx).Visible = False
        End If ` 

"Run-time error '1004'
Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Also if I use "Barkodas" instead of "[Prekė].[Barkodas].[Barkodas]" I get the same error on this line.

Comment: Hey @user2179129, bummer! That 1004 error is very interesting. I would love to help troubleshoot more, but do you think you could send a screenshot of your pivot table and data source to help me better understand the filtering and source of the problem?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oqu6o5l978zurzn/example.jpg
Here's an example of table. However I have no access to data source.